# Is f unbounded if directional derivative is constant?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

This is a basic doubt in multivariable calculus. Let $f:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$ be a smooth function with $\frac{\partial f}{\partial n}=c$ everywhere in $\mathbb R^n$ where $\frac{\partial f}{\partial n}$ is directional derivative along unit vector $\hat n$ and $c$ is a positive constant. I think $\,f\,$ has to be unbounded but I can't prove it.

Comment: Do you mean that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial n}(\mathbf{x})=c$ for all $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: @zipirovich yes

Comment: there are a lot of directions to examine here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can define a new function of a single variable $g(t)=f(t\mathbf{n})$, where $\mathbf{n}$ is the unit vector from your question. Then $\displaystyle g'(t)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial\mathbf{n}}(t\mathbf{n})$ pretty much by definition. So $g'(t)=c$ on all of $\mathbb{R}$, and therefore $f(t\mathbf{n})=g(t)=ct+K$ for the original nonzero constant $c$ and some constant $K$, showing that its values are unbounded.